# Swipe from fragment with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, swipe, navigation-drawer

Im developing an application that has a `Navigation Drawer`. In the drawer there are 3 options. Places, Logbook, Settings. I want to be able to swipe from each of these fragments to a fourth fragment. Almost like the Google Play application but without the visable tabs in the actionbar. Im not really sure where to begin, and I would be greatfull for som help.

To build the action drawer, I looked at this guide: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: What is your main navigation? You use `Navigation Drawer` with 3 items in it. And you use also swiping views with `ViewPager`?

Comment: Right now, i only have the `Navigation Drawer` with 3 items inside. Nothing else. I want to have one more fragment/activity that can be accessed only by swiping from right to left.

Comment: Why not use an additional Navigation Drawer to the right. What you are saying is achievable of course but having an additional Navigation Drawer will be much more simple

Comment: Im going to have a few settings and stuff on that Fragment. But maybe that is the best solution. How do i proceed with that, right now, the `Navigation Drawer` is created in my `Main Activity`, and the "fragment switch" is in there too. Do i create the additional `Navigation Drawer` in my `Main Activity` too?

Comment: In your layout `xml` file, there are children of `DrawerLayout`. The one with `layout_gravity="left"` will be the left menu, the one with the `layout_gravity="right"` will be the right menu. Just add your `Fragment` as a child in your xml file and set the gravity to right or end

Comment: Im sorry for lots of questions, but how do i add my `Fragment` as a child?

Comment: With a <fragment> tag in your layout. You should Google it. It is pretty easy.

Comment: Im not really sure what to do. Should i only modify the `xml` layout file? Please explain further. Where am i going to specify what the right `Navigation Drawer` will contain?

Comment: Yes only way to do is to edit the xml file. It should be the exact same way you add the left drawer. Only difference is to set the gravity to right. It doesn't have to be Fragment at all. Just add a LinearLayout there with layout gravity=right

Answer (score 0):

may be this one help you....

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Places", "Logbook", "Settings" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

and manifest file is like this,

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```